# Need to centre align div using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i m trying to center align three divs using bootstrap. i have a div with class container and it has three divs in it. i am trying to center align these three divs in the browser. i can get them to the center but they appear centered left. below is the code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col col-4">
          1 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4">
          2 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4">
          Extra
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: They are meant to be in the center on the screen. Not on the top center. But the middle center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i have figured out what was the issue. And here is the code below. Both the container and the row div are to be set to h-100 and .d-flex class applied to the row div.

```
<div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row align-items-center d-flex h-100">
            <div class="col col-lg-3">
              1 of 2
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-6">
              2 of 2
            </div>
            <div class="col col-lg-3">
              Extra
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CHange your code to

```
<div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-4">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
      2 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-4">
      Extra
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried it. the three divs get squeezed to 1 col and centerd left

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
        <div class="col col-4 mx-auto">
            1 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4 mx-auto">
            2 of 2
        </div>
        <div class="col col-4 mx-auto">
            Extra
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the `mx-auto` class on your divs, I've also added the `text-center` class to center the text for effect.

See pen - https://codepen.io/buzztnt/pen/MWKVZpB

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">1 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">2 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Extra</div>
  </div>
</div>
```